# Elixir, Postman : How to post a json containing an association

Tags: json, postman, elixir

I have two tables : 'clocks' and 'users', and I'm trying to append them with a json post request via Postman. Knowing that a clock belongs to a user, what should my json look like in order to create a new clock associated to a user that already exists in my db ? And for a user that doesn't exist yet ? Here are my two schemas :

```
defmodule Theme01.Content.Clock do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Theme01.Content.User

  schema "clocks" do
    field :status, :boolean, default: false
    field :time, :utc_datetime
    belongs_to(:user, User)

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(clock, attrs) do
    clock
    |> cast(attrs, [:time, :status])
    |> validate_required([:time, :status])
  end
end
```

and

```
defmodule Theme01.Content.User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Theme01.Content.{Clock, Workingtime}

  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :username, :string
    has_many(:clocks, Clock)
    has_many(:workingtimes, Workingtime)

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:username, :email])
    |> validate_required([:username, :email])
    |> unique_constraint(:username)
  end
end
```

I've tried these two json's:

```
{
    "clock": {
        "status": "true",
        "time": "2019-12-14 16:08:13",
        "user": {
            "username": "John",
            "email": "john@wanado.fr"
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "clock": {
        "status": "true",
        "time": "2019-12-14 16:08:13",
        "user_id": "1"
    }
}
```

which both add a new clock with a 'nil' user component.

Any help will be greatly apreciated, thank you.

Comment: Without seeing the code of the controller it’s impossible to answer.

Comment: I generally would recommend avoiding relying too much on associations like this -- it's more straight-forward to deal with resources individually and if necessary, bind database operations together via a transaction.  I would manually separate out the relevant parts of the JSON in the controller and issue 2 db transactions.  You can test that more easily.  However, you should be able to make this work in one go if you use `cast_assoc/3` in your changeset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `:user_id` in the Clock changeset

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is incorrect. One _might_ `cast_assoc/3`, but also one might issue two separate queries to the DB, or do a user lookup and then use `id` in the query, or whatever else.

Comment: Casting `user_id` will make the 2nd json payload work as they want it to work. I am not suggesting this is the only way to write code. I am just unblocking a new developer who is still learning.